# Git: Find which commit is checked out on a remote

Tags: git, git-remote

I have a local repo, and this repo has a remote. I want to know which commit (by SHA number) is checked out **on the remote**, assuming the remote is not a bare repository.

Clarification: I don't want anything to do with tracking branches or any other kind of branches on my local repository. In fact I want a method that works even if my local repository is a bare repository. Imagine that my remote is `ssh://whatever/foo`, so I want to get the equivalent of SSHing into the server `whatever`, doing `cd /foo` and `git rev-parse HEAD`.

I don't want to do the above example directly because I can't guarantee that I'll have SSH access to the remote. I want a method that works regardless of the type of remote

I want the response to be a SHA, not a branch name

Comment: Use jthill's answer. As a side note, this even works on a bare repo, as all repositories must have a `HEAD`. (If `HEAD` refers to a branch that is yet to be born, you won't be able to *see* it this way, or at all really, but in that case there is no answer.) To put it another way, the hash ID you get is not "the commit that is checked out" so much as "the commit that is current", i.e., it still means something in a bare repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git ls-remote origin HEAD
```

(any repo reference will do for origin, you can used a url or a path)

Comment: For some reason I'm getting multiple entries, any idea how to get just the `HEAD`? https://gist.github.com/cool-RR/27b9825165791e4ec536f89af70c143a

Comment: It's a pattern match, `|awk '{$2=="HEAD"}'` to strip out the remote-tracking heads.

Comment: Yeah, I also did a similar pattern match in Python, I just wish I wouldn't have to do it because you never know when these things will fail. It would be nice if there was a way to get the pure answer from Git without having to do text parsing. If you know of a way, please let me know.